# How to color individual point in a stripplot based on value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, stripplot

I am trying to color specific points on the seaborn:stripplot based on a defined value. For example,

`value=(df['x']=0.0`

I know you can do this with regplot, etc using:

`df['color']= np.where( value==True , "#9b59b6")` and the 
`scatter_kws={'facecolors':df['color']}`

Is there a way to do it for the `pair grid` and `stripplot`? Specifically, to color a specified value in `t1` or `t2` below?

I have also tried passing the `match` var in `hue`. However, this produced image #2 below and is not what I am looking for.

Here is the `df`:

```
par        t1         t2    found   
30000.0   0.50       0.45     yes   
10000.0   0.30       0.12     yes   
3000.0    0.40       0.00     no
```

Here is my code:

```
# Import dependencies
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Make the PairGrid
g = sns.PairGrid(df.sort_values("par", ascending=True),
                 x_vars=df.columns[1:3], y_vars=["par"], 
                 height=5, aspect=.65)

# Draw a dot plot using the stripplot function
g.map(sns.stripplot, size=16, orient="h", 
      linewidth=1, edgecolor="gray", palette="ch:2.5,-.2,dark=.3")

sns.set_style("darkgrid")

# Use the same x axis limits on all columns and add better labels
g.set(xlim=(-0.1, 1.1), xlabel="% AF", ylabel="")

# Use semantically meaningful titles for the columns
titles = ["Test 1", "Test 2"]

for ax, title in zip(g.axes.flat, titles):

    # Set a different title for each axes
    ax.set(title=title)

    # Make the grid horizontal instead of vertical
    ax.xaxis.grid(False)
    ax.yaxis.grid(True)

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

I am trying to color the point with the `value=0.0` a different color:

[image]

Passing the `match` var into `hue` produces the below and removes the 3rd `par=3000` value and collapses the plot. I can categorize the outliers I want highlighted a different color. However, the outlier value is removed from the y-axis and plot collapsed..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want a `stripplot`? It looks to me like you are actually trying to plot a `scatterplot`?

Also, I think you want to use a `FacetGrid` instead of a `PairGrid`? In that case, it requires to transform your dataframe in "long-form".

Here is what I got:

```
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['par','found'], var_name='Test', value_name='AF')

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df2, col='Test', col_order=['t1','t2'], hue='found',
                  height=5, aspect=.65)

g.map(sns.scatterplot, 'AF','par',
      s=100, linewidth=1, edgecolor="gray", palette="ch:2.5,-.2,dark=.3")
```

[image]